# Cypress assertion fails but test is marked passed (green checkbox) in the Cypress UI. Is this expected?

Tags: cypress

It looks like Cypress tests are marked with a green checkbox even if an assertion fails.  Has anyone encountered this?

I tried adding `Cypress.on("fail", (err, runnable) => { return false; });` to the index.js file in cypress/integration/support folder and this didn't help.

Here is a simple test showing the problem.  If you run the test you should see a green checkbox in the Cypress runner but if you expand the test to look at each step you will see the failed assertion in red:

```
describe('fail intentionally', () => {

    it('should fail when some random element that does not exist on page is asserted', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.google.com');
        cy.get('[name=btnK]').should('be.visible');
        cy.get('[name=totallyfake12345').should('be.visible') //expected to not be on the page

    });
});
```

[image showing Cypress UI view after running above test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRg9d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the line `Cypress.on("fail", (err, runnable) => { return false; })` actually causes the problem.

If I comment it out, the test fails as expected

[image]

Just shows why it's dangerous to apply this event modifier.

If there is an application error to avoid, it's better to apply it once only

```js
Cypress.once("fail", (err, runnable) => { return false; })
```

Comment: Thanks.  It worked for me.   I originally didn't have this line of code in my index.js and was still getting the green checkbox for failures.  However, the test I was fighting with was changed updated numerous times today and I didn't think to take it out before writing the google example.  Hopefully someone learns from this!